# loading different video background when user refreshes the page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What's the best way to load a different video background when user refreshes the page? I seem this done in flash but that's not what I want.  Thank you.

Comment: Can you rephrase this question so that it doesn't attract opinion-based answers and demonstrates an effort to do this yourself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it this way:

1. Initialize a set of video sources in an `array`.
2. Randomly pickup a video among these sources using [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) and apply it to your webpage.
3. If you want different video after every refresh, save the source path in `localStorage` and check it after refresh.

Keep it simple. :)